# Why does the `conf.level` argument have no impact on the result of the `binom::binom.confint` function?

Tags: r, statistical-test

```r
library(binom)

x <- 10  
n <- 20 

binom.confint(x, n, methods = "prop.test", conf.level = 0.80)
#      method  x  n mean    lower    upper
# 1 prop.test 10 20  0.5 0.299298 0.700702
binom.confint(x, n, methods = "prop.test", conf.level = 0.95)
#      method  x  n mean    lower    upper
# 1 prop.test 10 20  0.5 0.299298 0.700702
```

It does work with `binom.test` though

```r
binom.test(x, n, conf.level=0.80)$conf.int
# [1] 0.3381709 0.6618291
binom.test(x, n, conf.level=0.95)$conf.int
# [1] 0.2719578 0.7280422
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the package. According to the [docs](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/binom/html/binom.confint.html) for the `methods` argument:

> `prop.test`: equivalent to `prop.test(x = x, n = n, conf.level = conf.level)$conf.int`.

However, if we look at the [source](https://github.com/cran/binom/blob/c79bce79608360a7b617af3362cf824d082f6878/R/binom.confint.R#L140):

```r
if(any(method == "prop.test") || all.methods) {
    ci <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) stats::prop.test(x[i], n[i])$conf.int)
}
```

You can see that the `conf.level` argument is not passed to [`prop.test()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/prop.test), so it always uses the default (`0.95`). It should say:

```r
lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) stats::prop.test(x[i], 
    n[i], conf.level = conf.level)$conf.int)
```

This would lead to different output for different CIs:

```r
lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) stats::prop.test(x[i], 
        n[i], conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int)
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.299298 0.700702

lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) stats::prop.test(x[i], 
        n[i], conf.level = 0.8)$conf.int)
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.362262 0.637738
```

I am not entirely sure how to fix this. The [Github repo](https://github.com/cran/binom) seems to be read-only so you can't open an issue or Pull Request. Perhaps you could contact the package maintainers using the details on the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/binom/index.html). In the meantime you could try the hot fix below.

#### Hot fix

This is not the way to build a robust codebase but if you need a short-term solution you can patch the function like this:

```r
# Replace the relevant line
binom_confint_body2  <- sub(
    "function(i) stats::prop.test(x[i], n[i])$conf.int)",
    "function(i) stats::prop.test(x[i], n[i], conf.level = conf.level)$conf.int)",
    body(binom.confint), 
    fixed = TRUE
)

# Get access to binom.methods in the binom environment
binom_confint_body2  <- gsub(
    "binom.methods",
    "binom:::binom.methods",
    binom_confint_body2, 
    fixed = TRUE
)

# Create the function text
binom_confint2_txt  <- paste(c(
    'binom.confint2  <- function (x, n, conf.level = 0.95, methods = "all", ...) {',
    binom_confint_body2,
    "}}",
    collapse = "\n"
))

# eval the function text to create binom.confint2()
eval(parse(text = binom_confint2_txt))
```

Then we can run `binom.confin2`:

```r
# Run the function
binom.confint2(x, n, methods = "prop.test", conf.level = 0.95)
#      method  x  n mean    lower    upper
# 1 prop.test 10 20  0.5 0.299298 0.700702

binom.confint2(x, n, methods = "prop.test", conf.level = 0.80)
#      method  x  n mean    lower    upper
# 1 prop.test 10 20  0.5 0.362262 0.637738
```